# Javascript: Function to fill an object with the vowels as the keys and the count as the values

Tags: javascript, function, object, for-loop

As before, I have looked all over for the answer and I'm just a beginner and I am trying to learn from this and not just be handed the answer.

```js
var voweler = function (str) {
  var strArr = str.split('')
  var obj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    if (strArr[i] == 'a') {
      obj.a = 0;
      obj.a++;
    } else if (strArr[i] == 'e') {
      obj.e = 0;
      obj.e++;
    } else if (strArr[i] == 'i') {
      obj.i = 0;
      obj.i++;
    } else if (strArr[i] == 'o') {
      obj.o = 0;
      obj.o++;
    } else if (strArr[i] == 'u') {
      obj.u = 0;
      obj.u++;
    }
  };
  return obj;
}
voweler("This is a test")
//returns this which is wrong. Object {i: 1, a: 1, e: 1}
```

Comment: And what's the question ?

Comment: why isn't it counting the second letter i?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/1L9dpj0o/

Comment: Pay closer attention to the logic you've employed - reading out loud in plain English can really help: "If this character is the letter i, **set obj.i to zero**, then increment it".

Comment: @adeneo on line 8, I've never seen anything like that and I don't understand what it's doing.

Comment: It's a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 2):

Your code for updating the counts is wrong. Every vowel encountered, you run `obj.<vowel> = 0` which resets the count! To remedy this, set the counts *before* you enter the for loop and then in the for loop, only increment the counter.

If you'd prefer to only have an entry if the vowel exists, you can conditionally increment:

```
if(strArr[i] == <some_vowel>){
    if(obj.<some_vowel> === undefined)obj.<some_vowel> = 1;
    else obj.<some_vowel> ++;
}
```

Comment: I want to avoid having o: 0 in there though.

Comment: And why would that be?

Comment: Ideally I'd prefer to not return blanks, like if I was using this type of code elsewhere I'd want to not have to return a load of zeros.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of hints:

- Your loop will assign the property value for the key to 0 every time the character is a vowel, before incrementing.
- You can use toLowerCase() if you want to find upper and lower case vowels.
- You can use `indexOf`. It will return -1 if it cannot find the argument in a string.

```js
var voweler = function (str) {
  var strArr = str.toLowerCase().split('');
  var obj = {};
  strArr.forEach(function(ch) {
    if ('aeiou'.indexOf(ch) !== -1) {
      obj[ch] = (obj[ch] || 0 ) + 1;
    }
  });
  return obj;
}
console.log(voweler("This is a test"));
// Object {i: 2, a: 1, e: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might prefer something like this:

```
function voweler(input) {
    var result = {
        a: 0, e: 0, i: 0, o: 0, u: 0
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        var char = input.charAt(i).toLowerCase();

        if (result.hasOwnProperty(char)) {
            result[char] ++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because we can… and DTing has your answer already.

```
function countVowels(s) {
  var vowels = /[aeiou]/,
           o = {};

  s.toLowerCase().split('').forEach(function(c){
    if (vowels.test(c)) o.hasOwnProperty(c)? ++o[c] : o[c] = 1;
  });
  return o;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(countVowels('hi there')));
```

There is also:

```
function countVowels(s) {
  return (s.toLowerCase().match(/[aeiou]/g) || []).reduce(function(o, c) {
     o[c] = (o[c] || 0) + 1;
     return o;
  }, {});
}
```